# Java packaging, repeating package name?

Tags: java, packaging

I've finally started getting around to packaging my code and I've stumbled upon a strange little situation, I've been using the `com.myname.myproduct.*` packaging for awhile, but not that I have my website set-up I've been meaning to re-do all of my packaging.

The problem I've come across is that my website uses the `.net` TLD, and the software contains a `.net` package for it's networking code.

Is a package name such as

```
net.product.net
```

frowned upon by default, or is it perfectly fine?

Comment: It's perfectly fine.  There are no conflicts.  Packages only exist as fully qualified names in Java.  There are no "relative path" names;  meaning, Java does not have a notion of a "product.net" subpackage under "net", nor a "net" subpackage under "net.product".  There are only fully qualified packages like "net.product" and "net.product.net".

Comment: @VGR I think that is really an answer. ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. There are no conflicts. Packages only exist as fully qualified names in Java. There are no "relative path" names; meaning, Java does not have a notion of a "product.net" subpackage under "net", nor a "net" subpackage under "net.product". There are only fully qualified packages like "net.product" and "net.product.net".